# ImportError: cannot import name 'multilabel_confusion_matrix'

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am using python 3.6.3 and sklearn 0.20.3, but I am not able to print a multi-label confusion matrix.

```
from sklearn.metrics import multilabel_confusion_matrix
```

Output:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'multilabel_confusion_matrix'
```

I also tried to install a new version of scikit-learn. But it doesn't work for me.

```
conda update scikit-learn
conda install scikit-learn==0.21.dev0
pip install scikit-learn==0.21.dev0
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multilabel_confusion_matrix is introduced in scikit-learn version 0.21 and most recent nightly build scikit-learn doesn't contain it. The best way to get 0.21dev is :

`pip install git+http://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git`